# Extract subset from several file names using python

Tags: python

I have a lot of files in a directory with name like:

'data_2000151_avg.txt', 'data_2000251_avg.txt', 'data_2003051_avg.txt'...

Assume that one of them is called fname. I would like to extract a subset from each like so:

```
fname.split('_')[1][:4]
```

This will give as a result, 2000. I want to collect these from all the files in the directory and create a unique list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use os.

```
import os
dirname = 'PathToFile'
myuniquelist = []
for d in os.listdir(dirname):
    if d.startswith('fname'):
        myuniquelist.append(d.split('_')[1][:4])
```

EDIT: Just saw your comment on wanting a set. After the for loop add this line.

```
myuniquelist = list(set(myuniquelist))
```

Comment: The files themselves apparently start with "data_", fname was just the var.

Comment: He said to assume one was called "fname", I read to question to mean that he had a bunch of files mixed and wanted to find the fname's.

Answer (score 0):

For listing files in directory you can use [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.listdir). For generating the list of unique values best suitable is [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

```
import os
data = {f.split('_')[1][:4] for f in os.listdir(dir_path)}
list(data) #if you really need a list
```

Answer (score 0):

If unique list means a list of unique values, then a combination of [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) (in case the folder contains files that do not match the desired name format) and set should do the trick:

```
from glob import glob

uniques = {fname.split('_')[1][:4] for fname in glob('data_*_avg.txt')}
# In case you really do want a list
unique_list = list(uniques)
```

This assumes the files reside in the current working directory. Append path as necessary to `glob('path/to/data_*_avg.txt')`.

Comment: thanks, I want a unique list of years. E.g. 2000 must not be repeated twice

Comment: That's a set then, you can turn it in to a list if you want, just wrap the set literal with `list()`.